# when use robot_localization package my robot is glitch

Tags: ros, odometry, robot-localization, ros-noetic, robot

i have problem with my odometry when use robot_localization. before use this package, my pose odometry is so bad but no glitching. but when use this package, my odometry is better then before but the problem is glitching. anyone can help me with this problem?
i'm sorry for my bad english :)

[image: this is my problem, you can look my robot is glitching when use robot_localization package with wheel encoder and imu bno055]

this is my ekf.yaml

```
frequency: 30  # Frekuensi estimasi (Hz)
sensor_timeout: 0.1  # Timeout (detik) untuk setiap sensor
two_d_mode: false  # Mode dua dimensi (true/false)

transform_time_offset: 0.0  # Waktu offset transform (detik)
transform_timeout: 0.0  # Timeout untuk transform (detik)

odom_frame: odom  # Nama frame odom
base_link_frame: base_link  # Nama frame base_link

world_frame: odom  # Nama frame world
map_frame: map  # Nama frame map



odom0: /odomwheel  # Topik odometri
odom0_config: [false,  false, false,
               false, false,  true,
               true,  false, true,
               false, false,  true,
               false, false, false]  # Konfigurasi odometri (position, linear velocity)
odom0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true

        #        [x_pos   , y_pos    , z_pos,
        #         roll    , pitch    , yaw,
        #         x_vel   , y_vel    , z_vel,
        #         roll_vel, pitch_vel, yaw_vel,
        #         x_accel , y_accel  , z_accel]


imu0: /imu/data  # Topik IMU
imu0_config: [false, false, false,
              false, false, true,
              false, false, false,
              false, false, true,
              false, false, false]
 # Konfigurasi IMU (orientation, angular velocity, linear acceleration)
imu0_remove_gravitational_acceleration: true
imu0_rejection_treshold: 3
```